# why sqlite exception returned?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

i don`t know what should i do about  "not supported by PreparedStatment" exception.

my code is

```
connection = connectToDB();
        print("Connection Success");

        String sql = "Create Table test(id Integer primary key not null," +
                 "name Varchar(32)," +
                 "age Integer)";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute(sql);
        print("Created Table");

        sql = "Insert into test Values(1, 'Mr.Maeda', 23)";
        statement.execute(sql);
        print("Inserted Data");

        ResultSet result;
        sql = "select * from test";
        PreparedStatement preStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from test where age = ?");
        preStatement.setString(1, "23");
        result = preStatement.executeQuery(sql);
        while(result.next()){
            print(result.getString(result.getRow()));               
        }
```

and I am using eclipse & java.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call executeUpdate() instead of execute while inseritng the records:

```
 sql = "Insert into test Values(1, 'Mr.Maeda', 23)";
 statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

instead of

```
 sql = "Insert into test Values(1, 'Mr.Maeda', 23)";
 statement.execute(sql);
```

Difference between execute and executeUpdate:

> **boolean execute()** Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement
>   object, which may be any kind of SQL statement.
>
> **executeUpdate()** 
>             Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

For more information read [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I don't think this would solve the issue. I believe `execute()` will work as well for UPDATE.

Comment: Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, **which may be any kind of SQL statement.**

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
result = preStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

to

```
result = preStatement.executeQuery();
```

PreparedStatement.executeQuery() doesn't take the query string as an argument because it's already prepared it.